How to Retrieve the Transaction Hash When Using useWriteContracts with Coinbase Paymaster?
I'm working on a dApp using a paymaster service along with the useWriteContracts hook from the wagmi library. After submitting a transaction, instead of receiving a standard transaction hash, I'm getting a long ID. Here's a general outline of what my setup looks like:
const capabilities = useMemo(() => {
    if (!availableCapabilities || !account.chainId) return {};
    const capabilitiesForChain = availableCapabilities[account.chainId];
    if (
      capabilitiesForChain["paymasterService"] &&
      capabilitiesForChain["paymasterService"].supported
    ) {
      return {
        paymasterService: {
          url: `${document.location.origin}/api/paymaster`,
        },
      };
    }
    return {};
}, [availableCapabilities, account.chainId]);

const { writeContracts } = useWriteContracts({
    mutation: {
        onSuccess: async (id) => {
            console.log("Returned ID:", id);
            // I want to extract the transaction hash here
        },
        onError: (err) => {
            console.log("Transaction Error", err);
        },
    },
});

// Later in the code, I call writeContracts
writeContracts({
    contracts: [
        {
            address: contractAddress,
            abi: contractAbi,
            functionName: "function name",
            args: [function arguments],
            value: tx value,
        },
    ],
    capabilities,
});


Instead of receiving a typical transaction hash, the id returned is a long string like this:
0x9c5df149aee141828a73238bfd76218b73d4f70cdc1dd2f30362081fbd24b5bf0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014a34
I need the actual transaction hash to track the transaction on-chain (e.g., 0x1b1730bfba3a955b76dfdf74b11dc3088edb16c215ca30aaf131c3765c355f56). Is there a way to extract the transaction hash from the response, or another method to obtain it when using useWriteContracts with a paymaster?

I offer example code.
data = {
  chainId: chain.id,
  __mode: "prepared",
  abi: PresaleContractABI,
  address: "0x9e499f31906674fE5091067Fa83ccbe2851038Aa",
  functionName: "buyToken",
  args: [
    parseUnits(payTokenAmount, global.PROJECT_TOKEN.decimals),
  ],
  value: 0,
};

const preparedData = await prepareWriteContract(data);
const writeData = await writeContract(preparedData);

const txHash = writeData.hash;

const txPendingData = waitForTransaction(writeData);
toast.promise(txPendingData, {
  pending: `Waiting for transaction ${txHash} to be confirmed... `,
});

const txData = await txPendingData;

console.log("Transaction Hash:", txHash);


This doesn't work for paymaster, i followed the coinbase docs for setting up paymaster and it is using "useWriteContracts" which is imported from "wagmi/experimental".

There is a function named getCallsStatus.
https://wagmi.sh/core/api/actions/getCallsStatus#getcallsstatus
And here is an example:


let txStatus = {
  status: 'PENDING',
}

while (txStatus?.status === 'PENDING') {
  txStatus = await getCallsStatus(defaultWamigConfig, {
    id,
  })
}



